# How to overcome scope issue for generic button function?

Tags: winforms, powershell

I'm trying to use a generic button function in a script I'm writing, and I want to be able to pass a scriptblock or function to the `Add_Click()` method, but I think I'm having issues with scope. The code below wont work, but if I add a function to the `Add_Click` method it'll run that function when the button is clicked, but that defeats the purpose of a generic button that can be called multiple times with different actions.

```
Function New_Button {
    param(
        [string]$Button_Text,
        [int]$Button_X,
        [int]$Button_Y,
        [int]$Button_W,
        [int]$Button_H,
        [Object]$Button_Holder,
        [scriptblock]$Action
    )

    $Object_Button = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
    $Object_Button.Text = $Button_Text

    $System_Drawing_Point = New-Object System.Drawing.Point
    $System_Drawing_Point.X = $Button_X
    $System_Drawing_Point.Y = $Button_Y
    $Object_Button.Location = $System_Drawing_Point

    $System_Drawing_Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size
    $System_Drawing_Size.Width = $Button_W
    $System_Drawing_Size.Height = $Button_H
    $Object_Button.Size = $System_Drawing_Size

    $Object_Button.Add_Click({$Action.Invoke()})

    $Button_Holder.Controls.Add($Object_Button)

    return $Object_Button
}

[scriptblock]$Scriptblock = { Write-Host "It worked..."}

$Button_MyFirstButton = New_Button "Submit" 150 225 75 30 $Form_MainApplication $Scriptblock
```

Comment: Why do you want to pass code to a button? That code has to come from somewhere, why not just have the button reference wherever that code is coming from? Such as, if you are entering it in a textbox, have the button reference that textbox when it's clicked.

Comment: The New_Button function is made to be generic, so I can create multiple button objects with said function. So I need a way of applying a function or  scriptblock to the Add_Click() so the buttons can perform different actions.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand now. If you are creating an actual scriptblock then in your function have it read `$Object_Button.Add_Click($Action)`